# how to use xml to match a child element's attribute and calls the parent attribute?

Tags: xml, xslt, if-statement, foreach

**xml**

```
<school>
<courses>
<course credits="3" courseNum="COMP2899" name="XML for Developers" url="http://www.bcit.ca/study/outlines/comp2899">
  <prereqs>
    <prereq courseNum="COMP1850"/>
  </prereqs>
</course>
<course credits="3" courseNum="COMP1850" name="Introduction to Web Development and Design" url="http://www.bcit.ca/study/outlines/comp1850">
  <prereqs>
    <prereq courseNum="COMP1002"/>
  </prereqs>
</course>
</courses>
</school>
```

**xsl**

```
    <xsl:for-each select="./school/courses/course">
      <xsl:sort select="./@courseNum" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
      <xsl:if test="./prereqs/prereq/@courseNum = COMP1850">
          <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="@courseNum"/></td>
            <td><a target="_blank" href="{key('courseKey', @courseNum)/@url}">
                <xsl:value-of select="./@name"/></a></td>
          </tr>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

I want to call out the `courseNum, url and name` if the course's `prereqs courseNum` is `COMP1850` but somehow I have been trying a few things either it just doesn't do a thing or all page goes blank.

So basically if my prereq element's courseNum attr is COMP1850 then I want to call the attr value of the course element.

Can someone please give me a hand? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed to put the literal value `COMP1850` in single quotes..

`<xsl:if test="./prereqs/prereq/@courseNum = 'COMP1850'">`

Comment: OMG THANKS! I hate myself doing this! OMG!